# Configure logrotate in Chef

Tags: chef-infra

I am adding logrotate cookbook from chef supermarket into an existing cookbook. I would like logrotate_app to generate a configuration that includes 'postrotate' script.

This is what i have in my recipe:

```
logrotate_app 'myapp' do
  path '/var/log/glusterfs/*.log'
  options ['missingok', 'compress', 'delaycompress', 'notifempty','postrotate']
  frequency 'daily'
  rotate 7 
  create '644 root adm' 
end
```

This is result of my current config:

```
"/var/log/myapp/*.log" { 
  daily 
  create 644 root adm 
  rotate 7 
  missingok 
  compress 
  delaycompress 
  notifempty 
  postrotate 
}
```

I would like the final output to be like this:

```
/var/log/myapp/*.log { 
  sharedscripts 
  daily
  rotate 7 
  missingok 
  compress 
  delaycompress 
  notifempty 
  postrotate 
  /usr/bin/killall -HUP myapp > /dev/null 2>&1 || true 
  /usr/bin/killall -HUP myapp > /dev/null 2>&1 || true 
  endscript 
}
```

What would be the syntax to add below two lines in the recipe right after "postrotate" ?

```
/usr/bin/killall -HUP MyApp > /dev/null 2>&1 || true
/usr/bin/killall -HUP MyApp > /dev/null 2>&1 || true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
logrotate_app 'myapp' do
  path '/var/log/glusterfs/*.log'
  options ['missingok', 'compress', 'delaycompress', 'notifempty', 'postrotate']
  postrotate <<-EOF
    /usr/bin/killall -HUP myapp > /dev/null 2>&1 || true 
    /usr/bin/killall -HUP myapp > /dev/null 2>&1 || true 
  EOF
  frequency 'daily'
  rotate 7 
  create '644 root adm' 
end
```

The current list of possible "script" attributes is available here: https://github.com/stevendanna/logrotate/blob/1f0132fe74e68ff86a087521b6968aa77155c97d/libraries/logrotate_config.rb#L33

However I don't understand why you want to send the HUP signal to the same process twice.

Comment: Thanks Roland, it worked. Now I am writing chefspec test for lograte_app in my cookbook.

Comment: My rspec test fails as when I add                                                           `postrotate <<-EOF "/usr/bin/killall -HUP glusterfsd > /dev/null 2>&1 || true"
  EOF`                                                                                                        in my logrotate spec block. I think it is a syntax issue. Do you have any suggestion the rspec syntax?

Comment: Here is my chef spec that errors out 
         
`it 'creates appropriate logrotate config' do
        expect(chef_run).to enable_logrotate_app('glusterfs').with(
        create: '644 root adm',
        frequency: 'daily',
        path: ['/var/log/glusterfs/*.log', '/var/log/glusterfs/bricks/*.log'],
        rotate: 7
        options: %w(missingok compress delaycompress notifempty),
        postrotate <<-EOF "/usr/bin/killall -HUP glusterfsd > /dev/null 2>&1 || true"
        EOF
)
end`

Comment: `postrotate <<-EOF "/usr/bin/killall -HUP glusterfsd > /dev/null 2>&1 || true" EOF )` causes the test to fail. I need to figure out the correct syntax for this line.

Answer (score 0):

There are several examples [here](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/logrotate/blob/b7fe7d450adf701b476f59db0ed9a2c66ba58dd5/test/fixtures/cookbooks/test/recipes/resources.rb#L57) with usage of postrotate directive, so you may try to add this:

```
postrotate [
'/usr/bin/killall -HUP myapp > /dev/null 2>&1 || true',
'/usr/bin/killall -HUP myapp > /dev/null 2>&1 || true', 
]
```